# Two issues with Laravel view routing

Tags: php, laravel

I have this Laravel routes.php file:

```
<?php
use \App\Book;

Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
Route::get ( 'books', function () {
    $books = Book::all ();
    return view ('books')->with('books', $books);
} );
Route::get('books/{id}', function (int id) {
   return view('book', ['id' => id]);
});
```

And I'm having two issues with it:

First, the books view complains that $books is undefined, even though I passed it in.

And second, the book view doesn't even come up at all; I get a "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found" when I go to /books/1 in a browser.

What could be going on with my routing to cause these problems?

edit: here is my Book model code as requested:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    public string $title;
    public string $author;
    public int $copyrightDate;
}
```

Comment: you don't have a route for `book/{id}` .. you have one for `books/{id}`

Comment: Oops, I meant to say /books/1; let me go fix that.

Comment: Could we see your Book model's code?

Comment: @Adam Sure! Let me go edit that into my post...

Comment: Also, sometimes running composer `dump-autoload` will help clear up things, along with `php artisan views:clear` & `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Nope, those commands didn't work....

Answer (score 3):

try this sintaxys:

```
Route::get('book/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'book'.$id;
});
```

Comment: Oops! I didn't notice the missing $ because I haven't done much PHP... Why would I want to concatenate the $id variable with the view name though? Wouldn't that mean I need a book1, book2, book3, etc. view defined?

Comment: this is only for capturing the id from the url. as an example if book/32 is put on the url . then you get 32. as id. 
maybe this id does not exist in database. 
this route configuration is only for retrieving the id from url.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get ('books', function () {
$book = Book::all ();
return view ('books')->with('book', $book);
});

Route::get('books/{id}', function ($id) {
return view('book', compact('id'));
});
```

Try this.

Comment: `return view ('books')->with('books', $books);` Please change your view books to `return view ('bookRecord')` and then update your `books.blade.php` to `bookRecord.blade.php` so you will not get confused what variables or views that you've use.

Comment: That didn't seem to work either... Why would I want to rename books to bookRecord? I think books is a good name for a view that displays a list of books...

Comment: can you try php artisan route:list?

Comment: I get this table:

Comment: +--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD | books    |      | Closure | web          |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+--------------+

Comment: Try to clear route cache after route defined `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: You don't have a get head books/{id}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
use \App\Book;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('book/{id}', function ($id) {
    return view('book', ['id' => $id]);
});

Route::get ('books', function () {
    $books = Book::all();
    return view ('books', ['books' => $books]);
});
```

Make sure you have `/resources/views/welcome.blade.php`, `/resources/views/book.blade.php` and `/resources/views/books.blade.php`. Run `php artisan view:clear` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
use \App\Book;

Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
```

Make sure that your `books.blade.php` is exactly in `/views/books.blade.php`

```
Route::get ( 'books', function () {
    $books = Book::all();
    return view ('books', compact('books')); 
} );
```

Make sure that your `book.blade.php` is exactly in `/views/book.blade.php`

```
Route::get('books/{book}', function (Book $book) {
   return view('book', compact('book'));
});
```

Comment: Oh, I can pass a model object into a view like that? That sounds useful! How does Laravel know how to represent it in the URL when your path is books/{book}? And my views are in /resources/views/*.blade.php; should I move them out of resources? By the way, I still can't access the book view...

Comment: Yeah... You can pass your model instance like that. This link should give you more information. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: Yes you can do that. In laravel 5.5+ it is called route model binding. No i meant in `resources/views/*.blade.php` but not in subfolders inside views. if you have them like `/resources/views/books/index.blade.php` than you should return the view like this `return view('books.index', compact('books'));`

Answer (score -1):

Move the third route above the second route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('books/{id}', function (int id) {
   return view('book', ['id' => id]);
});
Route::get ( 'books', function () {
    $books = Book::all ();
    return view ('books')->with('books', $books);
} );
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything... do more specific rules need to go above less specific ones or something?